# Getting NPE while redirecting to the same JSP page after submitting a form

Tags: html, forms, jsp, nullpointerexception

After submitting a form on the profile page it goes to the controller where it then updates a database to then redirect back to the same page that the form was on. However i get an error trying to return to the same page. I can however redirect to another page without any issues?
Any help would be great.

**The Form**

```
<form action="controller" method="post">
                    Link Name:<br>
                    <input type="text" name="createLinkName">
                    <br>
                    Link Content:<br>
                    <input type="text" name="createLinkContent">
                    <br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="command" value="createLink" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
```

**Catching The Form Request**

```
else if (command.equals("createLink"))
                {
                    String linkName = request.getParameter("createLinkName");
                    String linkContent = request.getParameter("createLinkContent");
                    User sessionU = new User();
                    sessionU = (User)request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
                    int userID = sessionU.getId();
                    System.out.println(userID);
                    createLink(request, response, linkName, linkContent, userID);
                }
```

**createLink()**

```
protected void createLink(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String name, String content, int userID) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    profileHandler ph = new profileHandler();
    ph.createLink(request, response, name, content, userID);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("profilePage.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

**Handler that deals with the sql**

```
public class profileHandler {

private final DatabaseManager dbMgr;

public profileHandler()
{
    this.dbMgr = new DatabaseManager();
}
public void createLink(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String name, String content, int userID)
{
    dbMgr.establishConnection();
    String CREATE_LINK = "INSERT INTO linkedaccounts (linkname, linkaddress, userid) VALUES ('" + name + "', '" + content + "', " + userID + ")";

    dbMgr.prepareStatement(CREATE_LINK);
    dbMgr.executePreparedStatement();
    dbMgr.releaseConnection();
}
```

There isn't a problem with the sql as it is updated the Database just fine. Just wont allow me to eith stay on the same page as the form or just redirect back to it!

Thanks Again.
edit-
ERROR LOG:

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.profilePage_jsp._jspService(profilePage_jsp.java:66)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What is the exception or error you are getting?

Comment: @PrinceManiGupta org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Add it to the question and let us know which line of code is throwing NPE.

Comment: @PrinceManiGupta Have added the full error log.

Comment: what is this line 66? Check at that line,why you are getting null.

Comment: @PrinceManiGupta of the page im trying to link back to its the end of a for loop.

Comment: I guess you are seeing line 66 of your jsp.You need to check line 66 in profilePage_jsp.java.

Comment: @PrinceManiGupta Just looking for that file, thanks

Comment: @PrinceManiGupta       out.print( sessionU.getUsername() );

Comment: sessionU is coming null when you redirect.Handle that and you shud be ggood.